# How to compile an objective c program under windows with gnustep

Tags: objective-c, mingw

In this tut http://blog.lyxite.com/2008/01/compile-objective-c-programs-using-gcc.html it says that after installing gnustep for windows I can run gcc to compile my prog.

But where is it installed ? I can't find it under Gnustep folder though a GNUstep\mingw\bin folder with a bunch of files exist. So isn't the package install bugged ?

Someone asked the question and weirdly all the answers were out of subject:
[compiling Objective-C program on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305885/compiling-objective-c-program-on-windows)

When I go, there http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/
I have a bunch of folder of 1.9 Go I don't know what to download.

Update: There is indeed no gcc.exe but sh.exe instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to download MinGW from [this page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) and install it following the README file?

Answer (score 0):

blog post moved to

http://lyxite.blogspot.sg/2008/01/compile-objective-c-programs-using-gcc.html